# Count number of repetition for values in JSON nested arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck with something I thought would be easy. Let's say I have an object like this. I'm trying to insert in the div each name of the animal tagged and the number of times that tag is in types (for example, cat = 3, etc...)

```js
var animals = '';
animals = {
  "types": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    }
  ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  var tags = animals[i].tags;
}
```

```html
<div class="types">Number of animals:</div>
```

I'm a beginner with complex JSON objects, any help would be appreciated. It can be vanilla JS or Jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the snippet below, first loop iterates and counts each animal.

Second populates your div

```js
var animals = '';
animals = {
  "types": [{
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    }
  ]
}
var tags = {};

// Iterate over all your items
animals.types.forEach(function(type) {
  // Iterate over all the animals in the array
  type.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    if (tag in tags) {
      // If animal is present, increment the count
      tags[tag] = tags[tag] + 1;
    } else {
      // If animal is not present, add the entry
      tags[tag] = 1;
    }
  })
})

// Iterate over all the animals and add it to the div
for (var animal in tags) {
  if (tags.hasOwnProperty(animal)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('types')[0].innerHTML += ' ' + animal + ' ' + tags[animal];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="types">Number of animals:</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: Glad, I could help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this by using `map()` method :

```js
var animals = {
  "types": [{
    "id": "1",
    "tags": ["cat"]
   },
   {
    "id": "2",
    "tags": ["dog"]
   },
   {
    "id": "3",
    "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
   },
   {
    "id": "4",
    "tags": []
   },
   {
    "id": "5",
    "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
   }
  ]
 };

 var count = {};
 animals.types.map(function (arr, i) {
  arr.tags.map(function (tag, k) {
   count[tag] = (count[tag] || 0) + 1;
  });
 });
 console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) & [destrucuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it becomes one liner:

```js
var animals = {
  "types": [{
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(
   animals.types.reduce((r,{tags}) => tags.map(tag => r[tag] = (r[tag] || 0) + 1) && r, {})
)
```

Comment: Why do you need the `&& r`?

Comment: You need to return `r` from the reduce and `&& r` does it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `hash map` for all the tags and increment the count whenever you encounter that tag in that `types.tags` array

Then loop through the object and append that into your HTML Element

```js
var animals = '';
animals = {
  "types": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    }
  ]
}
let types = animals.types;
var counts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  types[i].tags.forEach((x) => { 
      counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; 
     });
}
console.log(counts);
```

```html
<div class="types">Number of animals:</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way:

```
var animals = { "types": [ { "id": "1", "tags": ["cat"] }, { "id": "2", "tags": ["dog"] }, { "id": "3", "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"] }, { "id": "4", "tags": [] }, { "id": "5", "tags": ["cat", "bird"] } ] }
var finalRes={};
animals.types.map(function(o, i){
o.tags.map(function(p, j){
    finalRes[p]=(finalRes[p]||0)+1;
});
});
console.log(finalRes);
```

Result:

```
{ cat: 3, dog: 2, bird: 2 }
```

Sorry, I am typing with mobile phone, slow but correct!

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten all tags into single array
2. Count each tag
3. Handle tag count as you need

```js
const animals = {
  "types": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    },
  ],
};

// Flatten all tags into single array

var allTags = [].concat(
  ...animals.types.map(
    (type) => type.tags
  )
);

// Count each tag

const tagsCount = {};

allTags.forEach(
  (tag) => tagsCount[tag] = tagsCount[tag] ? tagsCount[tag] + 1 : 1 
)
  
// Handle tag count as you need

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

app.innerHTML = Object.keys(tagsCount).map((key) => {
  return `<p>${key}: ${tagsCount[key]}</p>`
}).join('');
```

```html
<h1>Number of Animal Types</h1>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic javascript usage.

```js
// var animals = ''; // not needed
var animals = {
  "types": [{
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "tags": ["cat", "bird"]
    }
  ]
};

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < animals.types.length; i++) { // types is a key in animals object, animals is not an array
  var tags = animals.types[i].tags;
  if (tags.length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
      var tag = tags[j];
      if (typeof counts[tag] === 'undefined') {
        counts[tag] = 0;
      }
      counts[tag]++;
    }
  }
}


console.log(counts);
```